# OnPropertyChange issue

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

again I need your Help.
I have 3 WPF UserControl.
the 2nd use the 1st as a Template and the 3rd use the 2nd.

in the first one I have a Checkbox.
My goal is to call a method within the 3rd UserControl whenever the checkbox in the first UserControl is checked.

I pass the value from the checkbox through the 3 UserControls this way:

```
public bool IsCameraChecked
      {
         get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCameraCheckedProperty); }
         set { SetValue(IsCameraCheckedProperty, value); }          
      }

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCameraCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsCameraChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(ReplayController), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

and in the XAML I do this for the checkbox in the 1st UserControl:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ckbCamera" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Click="ckbActiv_Clicked" Margin="10,8,-10,6" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=_this,Path=IsCameraChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and I repeat the same for the second and third UserControl.

so far everything works as it should be if I call/ckeck the bool *IsCamerChecked* from the third UserControl it gives me exactly the value of the checkbox  (true or false)

The problem is now somehow I can't get it to work with OnProperty change.
I want to call a method from the 3rd UserControl allways when *IsCameraChecked* is *true*.

this What I did in the last 3rd UserControl:

```
 public bool IsCameraChecked
      {
         get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCameraCheckedProperty); }
         set
         {
            SetValue(IsCameraCheckedProperty, value);
            _isConnected = value;                
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }
      /// <summary>
      /// Called when any property changes.
      /// </summary>
      public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected void OnPropertyChanged()
      {
         EventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
      }      
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCameraCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsCameraChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(TWDebugRecorder), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

unfortunately the value of *IsCameraChecked* is only checked if I call it directly from any method 
but What I need is that when the chekcbox is checked in the 1st UserControl the value of *IsCameraChecked* in the 3rd UserControl become *true* and a notification if that value changes.
I hope you understood what I mean.
Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE Found Solution:
in the 3rd UserControl I changed the code to:

```
public bool IsCameraChecked
      {
         get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCameraCheckedProperty); }
         set
         {
            SetValue(IsCameraCheckedProperty, value);
            _isConnected = value;
         }
      }          

      protected static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         TWDebugRecorder temp = source as TWDebugRecorder;

         // here comes my method I wanted to call

      }     

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCameraCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsCameraChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(TWDebugRecorder), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnPropertyChanged));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad, that you have found by yourself, that you have to work with `PropertyChangedCallback`. You should not use a logic in `DependencyProperty`'s setter or getter, because they will only be called programmatically from code behind, XAML works directly with SetValue(..). So you have to use `PropertyChangedCallback` in 3. UserControl and move logic from Property-Setter:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCameraCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsCameraChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(TWDebugRecorder), new PropertyMetadata(false, CameraCheckedChanged));

private static void CameraCheckedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _isConnected = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
}
```